# prepending "REACT_APP_" for .env variable still returns undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, environment-variables

My react app's environment variables still returns undefined after trying to prepend "REACT_APP_" in my variable. I'm using create-react-app, and I see a lot of the prepending of "REACT_APP_" as the common solution for this, but it doesn't work for me.

**.env**:

```
REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_KEY=my_api_key
REACT_APP_OWM_KEY=my_api_key
```

In my **App.js**:

```
const get_random_photo = () =>
    `https://api.unsplash.com/photos/random/?orientation=landscape&w=1920&h=1080&query=${weather_query}&client_id=${process.env.REACT_APP_UNSPLASH_KEY}`;

 const get_weather = () =>
    `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${location}&units=metric&appid=${process.env.REACT_APP_OMW_KEY}`;
```

[image]

I also tried installing `env-cmd`, separating .env into a `.env.production` and `.env.development`, and editing scripts for package.json:

```
 "scripts": {
    "preinstall": "npx npm-force-resolutions",
    "start:staging": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts start",
    "start:prod": "env-cmd -f .env react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
```

And still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

If your .env files are named as `.env.production` and `.env.development` you are not using them in the package.json scripts.

It should be like `env-cmd -f .env.development react-scripts start` and your production build can be `env-cmd -f .env.production react-scripts build`

Comment: This feature is available with react-scripts@0.2.3 and higher. Hope you have those covered.

Comment: I have `"react-scripts": "^4.0.3"`. My env-cmd is version `^10.1.0`

Comment: Sounds good. I can't see any immediate problems with your code. Hope you had killed the current task and started a new one. Also no "" around your value in .env files.

Comment: Yeah I tried restarting the server a lot of times, and still no luck. I'm wondering if there are any packages or dependencies I should still be aware of.